# Java application design advice : storing image

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm starting a personal project (Java web application) to get some technologies I just learned into practice. I'm currently at the analysis/design stage and one of my concerns is to define how/where to store images.

Assuming I want to design and implement my web application the same way a commercial project would be, would you store image :

- as BLOB into the DB (I believe this option is never recommended)
- only the filename in DB + putting the physical files somewhere on the server
- using Content Repository tools such as JackRabbit

Any other suggestion and input are, of course, welcome.

Thx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images : DB or File System -](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234202/storing-images-db-or-file-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is better to store files in file system. It may happen that you are using hosting, that does not give you access to file system, then you need to use database.

Note, that you do not need to use SQL database, there is a plenty of options of NoSql datastores, which can handle storing files [better](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/183689081/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb).

In case of Content Repository (like Jackrabbit) you need to choose physical store as well. You can use either file system based store or database based store. See [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore).

Comment: I didn't mention it in my question but I happened to consider NoSQL DB too. Thanks a lot for reminding me