# How to read image from database

Tags: c#, sql

```
OleDbCommand and = new OleDbCommand();
c.Open();
and.Connection = c;
and.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MaleShoes WHERE IDhere=ID ";
OleDbDataReader read = and.ExecuteReader();
while (read.Read())
{
    label6.Text = (read[1].ToString());
    textBox1.Text = (read[2].ToString());
    pictureBox1.Image = (read[3].ToString());  
}

c.Close();
```

I got this error:

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Image'

How should I fix it?

My pictures are in my database on the third column.

Comment: how are they encoded(what format) in you DB??

Comment: The column in your database, does it hold the file (i.e. a blob field) or does it hold a path and filename of the picture?

Comment: Is read[3] contains path of image?

Comment: Or if read[3] contains ole object (binary)

Comment: As a sidenote, you should never "SELECT *" and rely on the position of your columns in the result. Name the columns either in the SELECT-statement or when reading from the DataReader.

Comment: is that path local and accessable from your application

Comment: it contains Ole object..

Comment: oh yeah..
I can put just the location of the image..

Comment: and also the error says it all, you tried to put an image which is actually a `string` int the `read[3].ToString()`, you need to convert it first into `bytes` using the 2 answers below :)

Comment: May I suggest to not use DB to store images? Take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234202/storing-images-db-or-file-system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you your database column contains the path to the image file, you should write:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile((string)read[3]);
```

If it is the image data (binary), you should write:

```
var bytes = (byte[])read[3];
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: in using this how what is the format of the path of image?


is it like this @"....\image.jpg"

Comment: @YOUn'Me The path can be relative path (`@".\Images\1.png"`) or abdolute path (`@"D:\Project\Images\1.png"`) to the image file.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this help (in case you are storing a binary):

```
pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage((byte[])read[3]);
```

And your method

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: don't forget `using System.IO` :)

Comment: it says parameter is not valid.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90908/Saving-OLE-Object-as-Image-Datatype-in-SQL It contains almost the same example.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this

```
  byte[] imagebyte = (byte[])read[3].ToString();

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  ms.Write(imagebyte, 0, imagebyte.Length);
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
  pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: ` byte[] imagebyte = (byte[])read[3].ToString();` what is read there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])read[1]);

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```